# Setting constraint so that new value in “Table A” must already exist in “Table B”, else return error?

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I'm trying to set up some kind of constraint so that I can only enter values in "Table A", if that value exists in "Table B".

I want this to act sort of like a selection list, where there are only a few values that exist in "Table B", which then restricts the values that can be entered into "Table A". (Kind of like a drop down list/ selection list)

I'm using pgAdmin 4 to access a PostGIS DB

Comment: Is this not what `FOREIGN KEY`s are for? p.s. welcome to the forum! 8-)

Comment: Apologies, I'm still learning all the terminology. I didn't realize a foreign key performed this purpose.
p.s. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint!

You should do something like [this](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/):

```
CREATE TABLE B (primary_key_value INTEGER PRIMARY KEY... other fields);

CREATE TABLE A (primary_key_field PRIMARY KEY, foreign_key_value INTEGER, other fields... 
CONSTRAINT 'name_of_fk_constraint'
FOREIGN KEY (foreign_key_value) REFERENCES B (primary_key_value);
```

If you try to `INSERT` a record into table A and the foreign_key_value field doesn't contain the value you're trying to insert in table B's `PRIMARY KEY` field (it can also be `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`), you will get an error and your `INSERT` will fail.

The classic example of this is the `orders` table and its child the order_line table.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (order_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, client_id, other_fields...);

CREATE TABLE order_line (order_id, part_name, part_id, other_fields...
CONSTRAINT 'order_id_fk' FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (order_id);
```

The `client_id` field in the `orders` table could (and indeed should) be a `FOREIGN KEY` into the `client` table - the critical thing about `FORIGN KEY`s is that they establish relationships between the different tables so that you have consistently correct data with the correct client per order and every order_line belongs to one and only one order. Do **NOT** be tempted to eliminate `FOREIGN KEY`s for "so-called" performance reasons - they are **VITAL** for a functioning database system.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel like I should have known this one, but your explanation was excellent! Thanks!